# How to know when the last element of a directive has been linked in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page with multiple elements from my directive. I need to fill these elements with data from an API, and I want to fetch data for all the elements with one API-call.

In the link function in my directive, I am adding every element to an array, so I have a collection of all the elements. This way I can fill all the elements with correct data when I get a response from the API. But I do not know when I have linked the last element, so I don't know when I can run the API call, and be sure to get the data for all of the elements. My question is how can I do this? How can I know that the previous element was the last one of this kind in the DOM, so I can run my API-call and fetch the data?

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('someElement', function (postContentFactory, $rootScope) {
        var postElements = [];

        function fetchData() { 
            console.log("I'm fetching data and putting it into the elements");
        };

        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                postElements.push(element);
                // if this is last element of this kind in DOM, I
                // want to run fetchData();
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/some-template.html'
        }
    }
)


<!-- HTML snippet that is server-side generated -->
<some-element id="12" type="someType"></some-element>
<some-element id="15" type="someType"></some-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directive is being run within `ng-repeat` there are several child scope properties that are added by `ng-repeat` directive

You can check within your directive for `scope.$last`.

If this isn't the case your question needs more detail on how you use your directive

Comment: It will be run within ng-repeat when it's included in infinity scroll. But I also need it to work without ng-repeat. I have added a code example for what usage I need it for.

Comment: curious why you need to fetch data based on DOM rendering. Never had to do that, and can't see why it would ever be needed. Also directive will be called for every element, so you won't have an array like you show in code

Comment: Only the link function will be run every time, the code above will be run once, and I will have the array. I need it because the HTML will be rendered server side, as I mention in the HTML snippet. I could fetch data for each element, but that would give me one request to the API per element. I would rather want to do one request for all the elements, and thus I have to be sure that I have all the elements in the array before making the API call.

Comment: why wouldn't you just use an angular template? Seems like a strange way to build an angular app. Server is generally only used as API and to serve templates and templates can often be set into js even

Comment: Because the users of our CMS should be able to build the HTML structure with a drag and drop UI. And thus we will be served the HTML structure, but we have to fill the elements with data fetched from an API.

Comment: then why not send the html with the other data? Just makes no sense that DOM render triggers an API request to get the html needed in the DOM

Comment: The API request fetches JSON data, which we fill into an Angular-template for the <some-element>. But we need to know which data to fetch, and that information is fed from the server in the initial HTML. The server creates a HTML-skeleton, and we will fill it with data. How is this different from any other site fetching bulk data to fill up a page from an API? How do you suggest we do it? By doing one request per element?

Comment: add the html as property sent with initial payload.